# Pandas function to create multiple columns based on a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset which looks like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 1.3 |
| A1 | 2 | 1.4 |
| A1 | 3 | 1.3 |
| A2 | 1 | 1.7 |
| A2 | 2 | 1.6 |
| A2 | 3 | 1.5 |
| A1 | 1 | 1 |
| A1 | 2 | 2.7 |
| A1 | 3 | 2.4 |
| A2 | 1 | 1.6 |
| A2 | 2 | 1.7 |
| A2 | 3 | 1.2 |

Desired output :

| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1.3 | 1.4 | 1.3 |
| A1 | 1 | 2.7 | 2.4 |
| A2 | 1.7 | 1.6 | 1.5 |
| A2 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.2 |

I have tried a pivot table but it's giving aggregation and without aggregation pivot it is showing a duplicate index error because of the duplicate index. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Have the input and outputs as editable codes so its easier to help you

Comment: Hi i have edited the question you can check it out now !

Comment: Does the column `A` have correct values? For example the second row - shouldn't it be `A1  1.0  2.7  2.4` ?

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely yes correctly pointed out I'll make the correction Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over using number of elements (assuming all combos have same number of elements) as follows:

```
dfx = df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc=list)
pd.concat([dfx.applymap(lambda x:x[idx]) for idx in range(dfx.apply(lambda x: len(x)).max())])
```

| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1.3 | 1.4 | 1.3 |
| A2 | 1.7 | 1.6 | 1.5 |
| A1 | 1 | 2.7 | 2.4 |
| A2 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.2 |

Old answer:

Seeing your sample dataframe, a simple pivot should do:

```
df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc='mean')
```

Comment: Hi ,As you see in the output i dont want it to aggregate

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index="A", columns="B", values="C", aggfunc=list)
df = df.explode(df.columns.to_list()).reset_index()
df.columns.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A    1    2    3
0  A1  1.3  1.4  1.3
1  A1  1.0  2.7  2.4
2  A2  1.7  1.6  1.5
3  A2  1.6  1.7  1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create an extra column that introduces uniqueness to your data, before pivoting:

```py
a = df.groupby('A').ngroup().diff().fillna(0, downcast = 'infer')
a = a.mask(a < 0, 1).cumsum()
(df
.assign(temp = a)
.pivot(['temp', 'A'], 'B', 'C')
.droplevel(0)
.rename_axis(columns = None)
)

      1    2    3
A
A1  1.3  1.4  1.3
A2  1.7  1.6  1.5
A1  1.0  2.7  2.4
A2  1.6  1.7  1.2
```